# Calling same function at two places works only for one instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have an angularjs app where I am calling a function foo(bar) that takes bar as parameter. The bar is a data that is coming from web api. I loop through this data using ng-repeat and all works good e-g

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat = "tag in subreddit.tags">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="subreddit.getData(tag)" target="_blank">{{tag.data.url}}</a>

      </li>
```

Here getData function works good. Now in the same app I define another instance of getData like below:

```
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="subreddit.getData(tag);">Load Feeds...</button>
```

This time get data wont work as thats obvious because the parameter tag is undefined while as in case of ng-repeat it was coming through from data.

I know it is hard to rephrase the question so I put up a demo to illustrate the problem.

Steps to reproduce:

Click on the reddit links and data gets populated correctly as you can see in console

but if you click on the red button Load Feeds which calls the same function it doesn't work. Can someone please tell me how to get this working or what am I doing wrong.

Demo of Issue:

http://jsbin.com/xexawumojo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Can't see how you expect it to work. The function get a parameter, and you don't have anything in case of the button. What tag you want to use when the button is clicked? The problem here is logic, not code

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining another instance you still use the same controller, but now, as you already write without a valid data object. because you are out of the repeat loop and so tag is unknown.

You could add a mouse click handler to save the selected tag in the controller and use this tag to load further.

Answer (score 0):

I really dont get the question but here I think you have missunderstood the concept here is the program that can help you a bit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="first" ng-controller="SubRedditController as subreddit">

   <ul class="list-group">
    <!-- you have declared tag variable over here so scope of the tag variable will be in below li only
    {from here -->
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat = "tag in subreddit.tags">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="subreddit.getTagAssociatedData(tag)" target="_blank">{{tag.data.url}}</a>

      </li>
    <!-- to here} -->

     <ul>
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-if="subreddit.full_description">
        {{subreddit.full_description.description}}
        <!-- <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="subreddit.getTagAssociatedData(tag);">Load Feeds...</button> -->
        <!-- you can not access tag variable over here because it is undefined. -->
      </li>
     </ul>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**And as the value you are passing is undefined that function will be called something like this**

```
vm.getTagAssociatedData = function(data) { 
// as data is undefined in second case          
var full_description = data.data; // full_description = undefiend
vm.full_description = full_description; // vm.full_description = undefined  
          console.log(data); // no output
        }
```